# How to add transitions to Flex box in ChakraUI

Tags: reactjs, css-transitions, chakra-ui

I am trying to make a restaurant website. At the moment, I am trying to create a hidden navbar that slides in from the top after scrolling past a certain y-coordinate on the window screen. I want to have the navbar ease in as a transition, however, when I try to pass this as a transition prop to my Flex it does not work.

Here is my code for the hiddenNavbar component.

```
export default function HiddenNavbar() {

    const fontStyle = {
        fontSize: {base: '1.5rem', lg: '3rem'},
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        maxH: 'full',
        _hover: {
          color: "brand.800",
        }}

    return (

          <Flex 
              bg='black' 
              padding='1.5rem' 
              width='full' 
              justify='space-evenly'
              position='fixed' 
              zIndex='1'
              transition='all 0.5s ease-in'
              >
              
              <Link 
              sx={fontStyle} style={{ textDecoration: "none" }} 
              href='#menu-section'
            >MENU</Link>

              <Link 
              sx={fontStyle} 
              style={{ textDecoration: "none" }} 
              href='#hero-meta'
            >LOCATION</Link>

            <Link 
              sx={fontStyle} 
              style={{ textDecoration: "none" }} 
              href='#hero-meta'
              >HOURS</Link>

              <Link 
              sx={fontStyle} 
              style={{ textDecoration: "none" }} 
              target="_blank" 
              href="https://www.latimes.com/socal/glendale-news-press/tn-gnp-et-0521-dining-20160524-story.html"
            >PRESS</Link>
              
          </Flex>
  ) 
}
```

Here is my heroSection component, which renders my hiddenNavbar component.

```
export default function HeroSection() {
  const [showNav, setShowNav] = useState(false);
  const scrollBreakpoint = 500;

  function setShowNavbar() {
    if (window.scrollY >= scrollBreakpoint) {
      setShowNav(true)
    } 
  }

  function hideNavbar() {
    if (window.scrollY < scrollBreakpoint) {
      setShowNav(false)
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener("scroll", setShowNavbar)
  window.addEventListener("scroll", hideNavbar)

  return (
      <Box 
        style={{backgroundSize: 'cover'}} 
        color='white' 
        width='full' 
        bg='black' 
        bgImage="url('/images/pho-image.png')" 
        bgRepeat="no-repeat" 
        bgPosition="center" 
        >
          
        {showNav ? <HiddenNavbar /> : null}
        
        <Container as='section' p={5} maxW={{base: '90vw', xl: '80vw'}} pb={20}>
              <Header/>
              <MenuNavbar/>
              <Divider borderWidth={1} borderColor='brand.700'/>
              <HeroMeta /> 
        </Container>
      </Box>
  )
}
```